# May I know why we need to add a const/var/let sometimes before arrow function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I just feel so confused that why we need to add this "const" before this mapStateToProps arrow function inside a component. For most other arrow functions we write inside React Component, we don't put a const or var or let before the arrow function. May I know what's the difference? Thank you so much!

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        user: state.user,
        math: state.math
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        setName: (name) => {
            dispatch(setName(name));
        },

    };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

```js
handleNdcChange = selectedNdc => {
        this.setState({ selectedNdc });

};

<Select
     value={this.state.selectedNdc}
     onChange={this.handleNdcChange}
     options={ndcOptions}
/>
```

Comment: Your second snippet doesn't appear to be valid syntax at all. Is this the complete file?

Answer (score 1):

When you add a method inside a class, that method is part of the class, so for instance:

```
class Test extends React.Components {
  myMethod = () => {}
}
```

How ever, since the mapStateToProps, is outside the class, it needs to be declared, that's why you need a `const`, `var`, `let`

A class is an object, so `myMethod` on this case, is part of that object.

The `mapStateToProps` is outside the class, then since is not part of the object, needs to be declared

Comment: No, `myMethod` is not part of the `Test` class object.